# Null Values when Using Predicates

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

The below example from Apple iOS document is full of crap and mistakes, I doubt if they ever put the code in Xcode!
[Null Values in Using Predicates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW1)

However I really want to know what writer really wanted to show the poor readers!
Could anyone correct those crappy code, make it meaningful for the topic?

Thanks!!!

================

Null Values
A comparison predicate does not match any value with null except null (nil) or the NSNull null value (that is, ($value == nil) returns YES if $value is nil). Consider the following example.

---

```
    NSString *firstName = @"Ben";
NSArray *array = @[ @{ @"lastName" : "Turner" }];
                    @{ @"firstName" : @"Ben", @"lastName" : @"Ballard",
                       @"birthday", [NSDate dateWithString:@"1972-03-24 10:45:32
+0600"] } ];
NSPredicate *predicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName like %@", firstName];
NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"filteredArray: %@", filteredArray);

// Output:
// filteredArray ({birthday = 1972-03-24 10:45:32 +0600; firstName = Ben; lastName = Ballard;})
```

---

The predicate does match the dictionary that contains a value Ben for the key firstName, but does not match the dictionary with no value for the key firstName.

Comment: Why would you expect it to give you an entry with no first name when you are filtering by first name?

Comment: If you want to fetch all firstNames thn why you are even applying predicate? Simply fetch all without using predicate. Still if you want to use predicate thn instead of setting firstName nil, set your predicate nil. NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:nil]; :p

Comment: @iVishal+@CrimsonChris: the demo code is from Apple's guide, which is all about predicate. Please click the link inside my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the correction. The literal is wrong:

```
NSArray *array = @[
                    @{ @"lastName"  : @"Turner" },

                    @{ 
                       @"firstName" : @"Ben",                                                                     
                       @"lastName"  : @"Ballard",
                       @"birthday"  : [NSDate dateWithString:@"1972-03-24 10:45:32 +0600"]
                     }
                  ];
```

I beautified it a bit. (Did I?)

It wants to show, that a comparison to a value that is `nil`, will always evaluate to `NO`, except the constant compared against is a kind of null (`nil`, `[NSNull null]`, and probably, but not documented `Nil`), too.

Furthermore, and this seems to be more important, it wants to show, that if you compare a kind of null value to a value that is `nil`, it evaluates to `YES`. This has to be clarified, because of the following problem:

```
id a = nil;
id b = a;   // Pretty equal

if ([a isEqual:b])
{
   // not reached, because isEqual: will return NO (nil behavior)
}
```

Comment: Amin Negm-Awad: thanks for the answer! if ([a isEqual:b]) is not reached, is because the contents of two "nil" objects (pointers) not equal?

Comment: It is, because the result of a message to `nil` is always 0 (what means `NO` for a boolean type). So it is only important that `a` is `nil`. (But if `b` is not `nil`, nobody wonders why `NO` is returned.